# Is it legal to distribute, in my .NET app, the interop contract (reference) from a third party COM DLL?

Tags: copyright, software

When you reference a COM DLL (xyz.dll) in Visual Studio, it creates a interop contract (file interop.xyz.dll) that is used to "communicate" with the DLL. It is usually embedded in your software. If DLL is from third party, is it legal to distribute my software including this interop contract (and, of course, without the COM DLL itself) ? It's for an open-source project and people would have to get this DLL separately.

Comment: What is the license that the third party DLL is provided under? What are the terms about reverse engineering?

Comment: Yes, license says that reverse engineering is not permitted. I'll take that as a no go then. Thanks!

Comment: @RonBeyer, bricx: the interop dll is not the product of reverse engineering. There may be terms in the license of the COM dll that would prohibit distribution of the interop dll, but a prohibition against reverse engineering is not among them.